# Gizmos still showing in game view even when disabled unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging

In my project, I want Debug.DrawLine to be visible in game view, so I have enabled gizmos, however, other gizmos such as the icon for text mesh pro objects are still showing.
[image]

I have disabled all the of checkboxes under the gizmos menu, and this has hidden colliders, but the objects in the image above are still showing.
[image]
Does anyone know what I can do to keep the Debug.DrawLine showing but hide the other gizmos?

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but if you collapse the script that is drawing the gizmos they will stop drawing.  Just click the title of your script to collapse it.

Comment: @hijinxbassit do you mean the script that instantiates the objects? Most of the text objects and the scroll objects were added manually. I tried collapsing the components of the text objects and scroll bar, but that didn't do anything. I also tried collapsing the scripts which instantiated the text objects that are instantiated, but that didn't do anything either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to press on the icon instead of gizmos to remove those TMP gizmos

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that made the TMP gizmos disapear. I still haven't worked out how to get rid of the red lines on the scroll bar, though.

Comment: IMK unity does not have anything that draw this line by default, or you have some package or some of your scripts are drawing this, look for OnDrawGizmos AND OnDrawGizmosSelected on your codebase